# Multilingual input method library in cross-platform

Tags: c++, c, internationalization, ime

Up to now when I need input method support for languages that don't use the Roman alphabet, I'd call winapi, and test it in Wine to claim cross-platformness.

While I can learn and use the X input method handling for Linux, then I have a problem of not having native support for Apple computers, and so on.

So I'm looking for a cross platform library to do this. Either in C or C++ is fine. I certainly had a search on google, without satisfying results.

I prefer not to link with a huge widget toolkit such as Qt or GTK as those libraries themselves will be several times bigger than my application. But at least let me know if I have no choice.